# Vector-space library and constraining the scalar type

Tags: haskell, types

I'm working on a program that uses the [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.8.6) library, and I'm having some troubles with using it.
See the code below.

```
import Data.VectorSpace
-- scale a vector with a float
step :: (VectorSpace a) => a -> Float -> a
step x dt = x ^* dt
```

When compiling this code segment I get errors regarding the associated scalar type for the vector typeclass.

```
Could not deduce (Scalar a ~ Float)
from the context (VectorSpace a)
  bound by the type signature for
        step :: VectorSpace a => a -> Float -> a
  at Test.hs:5:9-42 
In the expression: x ^* dt
In an equation for `step': step x dt = x ^* dt
```

Is there a type signature that will fix this compiler error? Or is there a better library to use for descibing the operations that I'm looking for in a type (like addition and scaling)? In the end I'm hoping to use the code like for things.

```
step (1,1) 0.5
step 1 0.5
```

Essentially I'm hoping to reuse some of the instances that vector-space defines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: found signature on hackage to be incorrect

You can just add the constraint about which GHC complained:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Data.VectorSpace

step :: (VectorSpace a, Scalar a ~ Float) => a -> Float -> a
step x dt = x ^* dt
```

Comment: The issue here though is that the only scalar value I want/can use is Float. Is it possible to restrict `a` so that I can use floats as the scalar, and at the same time be able to use instances of `VectorSpace` like `(Float, Float)` and `Float` with it?

Comment: @chanko08 I've checked the actual type signatures and corrected the answer

Comment: This does typecheck in ghci, but it seems there's something missing when it's used. For example, if you try running `step (0.1, 0.1) 2.0` you get an ambiguity error. How do you get around that?

Comment: @chanko08 In ghci you need to specify exactly what type do you need, e.g. `step (1.0, 1.0) 3.0 :: (Float, Float)`. Or, use as `x` argument some value whose type is known to GHC. In more or less complete code the types usually can be derived, but in a standalone expression in ghci there's not enough information.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Specifying the exact type got rid of the ambiguity error, thank you.